# Getting first and last day of the current month

Tags: c#, date

I have here 2 datepicker for **start date** and **end date**.

how can I get the first day and last day of the current month

```
rdpStartDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
rdpEndDate.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: If you want to get to the final time for the month, then use AddTicks(-1) instead of AddDays(-1)

Comment: @InquisitorJax In that case, I would favor just using `<` or `>` in your logic instead of `<=` or `>=` if at all possible. You can run into precision bugs with other systems if, for example, your program thinks the cutoff is `<= 2019-10-31T23:59:59.9999999`, but the database server or remote server interprets the cutoff as `<= 2019-10-31T23:59:59.999`. You won't have that problem if you specify `< 2019-11-01T00:00:00.0000000` instead.

Comment: @BaconBits what do you mean by < or >

Answer (score 42):

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var first = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var last = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

You could also use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var last = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month));
```

Answer (score 12):

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now;
var startOfMonth = new DateTime(myDate.Year, myDate.Month, 1);
var endOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

That should give you what you need.

Answer (score 7):

Try this code; it is already built in C#

```
int lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth (2014, 2);
```

and the first day is always 1.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative way is to use `DateTime.DaysInMonth` to get the number of days in the current month as suggested by @Jade

Since we know the first day of the month will always `1` we can use it as default for the first day with the current Month & year as `current.year,current.Month,1`.

```cs
var now = DateTime.Now; // get the current DateTime 

//Get the number of days in the current month
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth (now.Year, now.Month); 
    
//First day of the month is always 1
var firstDay = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,1); 
    
//Last day will be similar to the number of days calculated above
var lastDay = new DateTime(now.Year,now.Month,daysInMonth);

//So
rdpStartDate.SelectedDate = firstDay;
rdpEndDate.SelectedDate = lastDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string firstdayofyear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
string lastdayofyear = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
string firstdayofmonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
string lastdayofmonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your answer. Why strings? How does this answer improve on the many answers already posted?

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question in any different way rather uses the same logic as answered above ad adds unnecessary **firstdayofyear** and **lastdayofyear** which is not even asked here.

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, the day part of a `DateTime` is 21 then subtract 20 days from it to get the first day of corresponding month:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime firstDay = today.AddDays(-today.Day + 1);
DateTime lastDay = today.AddDays(-today.Day + 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Sample output:

```
today    = 03/21/2023 12:00:00 AM
firstDay = 03/01/2023 12:00:00 AM
lastDay  = 03/31/2023 12:00:00 AM
```