# How to set datetimepicker value to 1st of selected month automatically?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datetime

when i check monthwise radiobtn the datetimepicker value should automatically set to 1st day of selected month.

how to do this??

tried

```
dtpDate.value=new Date(1:MM:YYYY)
```

but not working as expected..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
 dtpDate.Value = Now.Date.AddDays(-(Now.Day) + 1)
```

`Date.AddDays` will add specified number of days to the date mentioned

`Now.Day` will give the current day

`dtpDate.Value = Now.Date.AddDays(-(Now.Day) + 1)` will always points to the first day of current month

**Updates:** set date to 01 of selected month on month change

```
   Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
     DateTimePicker1.Value = CDate("01/" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Month & "/" & DateTimePicker1.Value.Year) 
   End Sub
```

Comment: I want like this. If I select MARCH , DTPVALUE should go to 1st of MARCH. Like that i need to set.  is it possible?

Comment: is there any way to extract date,month part from datetimepicker using vb.net. so that i can set the date

Comment: Your update to select the first of the month on a date change is not locale friendly so won't work on locales using MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [DateTime Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new date value using 1 as the day of the month and set the datetime picker to that value:

```
dtpDate.Value = New DateTime(dtpDate.Value.Year, dtpDate.Value.Month, 1)
```

Comment: plus for using built-in constructors

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer very useful and very easy. I have provided the link below.

[Getting first and last day of the current month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923341/getting-first-and-last-day-of-the-current-month)

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 var startDate = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
 var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Originally Posted by Marcin Juraszek (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163867/marcinjuraszek)

Answer (score 0):

You can change manually date, month and Year of the Selected DateTime in C#
by using this I m changing the Selected Date only and set Selected Date 1st Of the selected moth year...

```
 var moodifiedDate = new DateTime(input.Year, input.Month, 1)
```